# Can not access the windows service description through the service controller in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, servicecontroller

I have this Windows Service from my company :

[image]

I want to get the service description from it in code behind! but for some reason it does not return the service description.

Can anyone help me with this .

here is my code, and what it returns :

```
Dim MyServices As ServiceController = New ServiceController("AccTech Exchange Rate Import")
    Dim Status As String = MyServices.Status.ToString
    Dim Name As String = MyServices.ServiceName
```

and what the MyService variable returns.

[image]

How would i get the Service Description from here?

Regards,

EDIT:

Here is my code after Miki Shah pointed me in the right direction!

```
Dim MyServices As ServiceController = New ServiceController("AccTech Exchange Rate Import")

Dim Status As String = MyServices.Status.ToString
Dim Name As String = MyServices.ServiceName
Dim Description As String

Dim objPath As String = String.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", Name)
Using service As New ManagementObject(New ManagementPath(objPath))
    Description = service("Description")
End Using
```

Comment: may  be you can get Decription using System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller class.

Comment: i shall try that now, and give a reply . and thanks for quick response

Comment: edit :  how would the code look to make the installer use the service that is chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get as following way, and have to add reference of System.Management

```
string serviceName = MyServices.ServiceName
string objPath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", serviceName);
using (ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(objPath)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(service["Description"]);
}
```

Comment: this is C#, i cant seem to get the Managmentobject in vb.net... and i don't understand this code completely? if you care to explain.
and thanks for the effort.

Comment: nevermind, i got the code to work, but i still dont understand, what this code does? do i give my variable this service as property?

Comment: 1.you have to add System.Management reference, 2. Code is using main ManagementObject which is used to get information related to system. here we have service name, now we get service information using ManagmentObject class. WMI process is very good.pls refer if you not aware about this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwd0y33x.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `QueryServiceConfig2` Win32 API to get the Windows service description. This method is far more fast compared to the WMI solution.

The code below is written in C#, however it can be easily converted to VB.NET
[converter.telerik.com](https://converter.telerik.com/)

[image]

1. Specify the service name.
2. Get the SCM database handle using the `OpenSCManager` Win32 method.
3. Open the service handle using `OpenService` Win32 API, specifying the service name and SCM handle.
4. Call the `QueryServiceConfig2` with empty buffer, the `pcbBytesNeeded` parameter receives the needed buffer size.
5. Allocate the buffer with the required size using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`.
6. Call `QueryServiceConfig2` again with the allocated buffer and buffer size.
7. Convert the buffer to `SERVICE_DESCRIPTION` structure.
8. Free the buffer and close the all the open handles.

   ```
       using System;
       using System.Diagnostics;
       using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

       namespace Test
       {
       internal class Program
       {

       #region "Constants"

       const uint ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;

       const uint SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG = 0x0001;
       const uint STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_CONNECT = 0x0001;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE = 0x0002;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE = 0x0004;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_LOCK = 0x0008;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS = 0x0010;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG = 0x0020;
       const uint SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_LOCK | SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS | SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG;

       #endregion

       #region "Win32 APIs"

       [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
       static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string lpMachineName, string lpDatabaseName, uint dwDesiredAccess);

       [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
       static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, uint dwDesiredAccess);

       [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
       static extern bool QueryServiceConfig2(IntPtr hService, SERVICE_CONFIG dwInfoLevel, IntPtr lpBuffer, uint cbBufSize, out uint pcbBytesNeeded);

       [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
       static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr hSCObject);

       #endregion

       #region "Enumerations"

       public enum SERVICE_CONFIG : uint
       {
           SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION = 1,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS = 2,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_DELAYED_AUTO_START_INFO = 3,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS_FLAG = 4,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_SERVICE_SID_INFO = 5,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_REQUIRED_PRIVILEGES_INFO = 6,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_PRESHUTDOWN_INFO = 7,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_TRIGGER_INFO = 8,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_PREFERRED_NODE = 9,
           SERVICE_CONFIG_LAUNCH_PROTECTED = 12
       }

       #endregion

       #region "Structures"

       [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
       public struct SERVICE_DESCRIPTION
       {
           public string lpDescription;
       }

       #endregion

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {

           Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
           stopwatch.Start();

           string svcName = "Power"; // Change this to the service name you want to get its description

           // Get the SCM database handle
           IntPtr schSCManager = OpenSCManager(null, null, SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG);

           // Get the service handle

           IntPtr schService = OpenService(schSCManager, svcName, SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG);
           if (schService == IntPtr.Zero)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Win32 API OpenService failed ({0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
               return;
           }

           // Query the service description
           IntPtr buffer;

           bool success = QueryServiceConfig2(schService, SERVICE_CONFIG.SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out uint bytesNeeded);

           if (!success && Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
           {

               buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)bytesNeeded);
               bool success2 = QueryServiceConfig2(schService, SERVICE_CONFIG.SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION, buffer, bytesNeeded, out bytesNeeded);

               if (!success2)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Win32 API QueryServiceConfig2 failed ({0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                   return;
               }

           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Win32 API QueryServiceConfig2 failed ({0})", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
               return;
           }

           // Read the description from the buffer
           SERVICE_DESCRIPTION description = (SERVICE_DESCRIPTION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(SERVICE_DESCRIPTION));
           Console.WriteLine("{0} service description: {1}", svcName, description.lpDescription);

           // Free the buffer and close the handles
           Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
           CloseServiceHandle(schService);
           CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);

           stopwatch.Stop();
           Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: {0} Milliseconds", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

           Console.ReadLine();

       }

   }
   ```

   }

**References:**

[OpenSCManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-openscmanagerw)

[OpenService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-openservicew)

[QueryServiceConfig2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-queryserviceconfig2w)